# Array.push is not working with objects in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How can I add an object as an entry to an array, like I'm trying to do here...

```
 displayAccounts(function(data){
    var index;
    var accs = new Array();
    for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
      rclient.get(data.account, function (info) {
        accs.push({
            account: data.account,
            info: info
          });
      });
    }
    console.log(accs);
  });
```

Output:

```
accs = []
```

Desired solution:

```
accs = [{account: 'jak', info: 0},{account: 'jil', info: 1}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that `rclient.get` is *asynchronous*, so examining the array after your loop is examining it too soon (the gets have been *started*, but they haven't finished yet); it will get filled in by callbacks that occur asynchronously. Wait until the last callback has occurred, e.g.:

```
displayAccounts(function(data){
    var index;
    var accs = []; // [] is a better way to write new Array()
    for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) 
        rclient.get(data.account, function (info) {
            accs.push({
                account: data.account,
                info: info
            });
            if (accs.length === data.length) {
                // We're done, *now* look at / use the array
                console.log(accs);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Note that depending on how `rclient.get` works, the callbacks may or may not occur in the same order as the requests.

---

Side note: That `rclient.get(data.account, ...` looks suspicious, you're repeatedly requesting the same information. Perhaps `rclient.get(data[index].account, ...`?

Comment: I'd also recommend using a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to perform asynchronous loops...

Comment: Yes, I did have to add `data = data[index];`  rclient is my redis client. The line `if (accs.length === data.length)` can't quite work because the entries are different.

Comment: @user14351: Your code above schedules a `get` for each entry in `data`, `accs` is empty to start with, and you `push` once for each callback. So `accs.length === data.length` is correct for the code you've shown. But yes, by all means, adjust it as necessary. The key point is that you don't want to use `accs` until the callbacks have occurred.